# Looping Through Two Uneven Loops

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops

Let's say I have two arrays goes like this:

```
string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
string[] names = { "Alice", "Brain", "Charlie", "David", "Elisa", "Francis", "Gordon", "Haley", "Isaac", "Jeniffer", "Kirkland", "Laura", "Michael", "Nora", "Oscar", "Pam" };
```

I have created two for loop, names loop was outside and months loop was inside. It didn't work.
My code was like this:

```
        for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(months[j] + " = " + names[k]);
            }
        }
```

What I want to achive an output like this:

```
Jan=Alice
Feb=Brain
Mar=Charlie
Apr=David
May=Elisa
Jun=Francis
Jul=Gordon
Aug=Haley
Sep=Isaac
Oct=Jeniffer
Nov=Kirkland
Dec=Laura
Jan=Micheal <-- Months Starts Again
Feb=Nora
Mar=Oscar
Apr=Pam
May=Alice <-- Names Starts Again
Jun=Biran
...
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const int itemsToDisplay = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < itemsToDisplay; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(months[i % months.Length] + " = " + names[i % names.Length]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to use two indexes here?

Comment: Ivan, you're right - one index is enough here. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need one loop only. This loop will go on for however long you need. Not very clear from your question how many times each name needs to appear. Let's assume the total length is 12*16 (months length times names length)

Loop over all names with index 'i' going from 0 to 12*16.
When you print out the relevant month and name, use:

```
monthIndex = i mod 12
nameIndex = i mod 16
```

This will give you the next month value and the next name value.

Answer (score -1):

Not a great solution but it should be clear; count through each array, print the string, reset the count at the end, continue

```
        string[] names = { "Alice", "Brain", "Charlie", "David", "Elisa", "Francis", "Gordon", "Haley", "Isaac", "Jeniffer", "Kirkland", "Laura", "Michael", "Nora", "Oscar", "Pam" };
        string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
        
        int monthCount = 0;
        int nameCount = 0;
        int loopCount = 0;
        while (loopCount < 20)
        {
            loopCount++;
            Console.WriteLine(months[monthCount] + "="+names[nameCount].ToString());
        
            if(monthCount < months.Length-1)
                monthCount++;
            else
                monthCount = 0;
            if(nameCount < names.Length-1)
                nameCount++;
            else
                nameCount = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
using System;

string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
string[] names = { "Alice", "Brain", "Charlie", "David", "Elisa", "Francis", "Gordon", "Haley", "Isaac", "Jeniffer", "Kirkland", "Laura", "Michael", "Nora", "Oscar", "Pam" };

for(int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
{
    var monthIndex = j % months.Length;

    var nameIndex = j % names.Length;

    Console.WriteLine($"{months[monthIndex]} = {names[nameIndex]}");
}
```